# Problem With Running ADT Eclipse In Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, eclipse, binary

I have downloaded `adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321`.
then,i unziped it with Terminal in `/home/username/Documents/Software/Programming`.
in the Eclipse folder,there is an executable  file called `Eclipse`.

How can i run it?i have used the `sudo chmod +x Eclipse`command,NO ERROR.but when i type the `./Eclipse` command,it says:

```
bash: ./eclipse: cannot execute binary file
```

What Should I Do?

Any Help Is Appreciated...

Comment: what is output of command `uname -i`?

Comment: the output is 'unknown'

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Linux ubuntu 10.10 is outdated, you should upgrade to a newer supported versions such as 12.04 LTS 14.04 LTS 14.10 or 15.04

Comment: I answered you check the answer

Answer (score 0):

This problem raises when you are installing package for different architecture. 
So this package is 64 bit, so you have to install a 32 bit, so go and download the 32 bit and do the same steps as above and everything will go smooth

Comment: OS or the Downloaded File?

Comment: the downloaded file